# I don't know how to display my customuser and user in same form

Tags: python, django

I have 2 models: teacher and student. They both extend User class with a OneToOneField and they both have receivers defined for creation and saving. Now, in my forms I can only display the fields from student or teacher only, the other fields that come with user I don't know how to include them. But I want that a student or a teacher won't be able to create account, unless all fields are filled in. Here are my forms and view:

```html
class StudentSignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('student_ID', 'photo', 'phone')


class TeacherSignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Teacher
        fields = ('academic_title', 'photo', 'phone', 'website', 'bio')
```

```html
class StudentSignUpView(CreateView):
    model = User
    form_class = StudentSignUpForm
    template_name = 'student_signup_form.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['user_type'] = 'student'
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = form.save()
        login(self.request, user)
        return redirect('index')


class TeacherSignUpView(CreateView):
    model = User
    form_class = TeacherSignUpForm
    template_name = 'teacher_signup_form.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['user_type'] = 'teacher'
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = form.save()
        login(self.request, user)
        return render_to_response('index.html', {'form': form},)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating another form for the `User` model and just include `UserForm` and `StudentSignupForm` in one `<form></form>` tag, and another `UserForm` and `TeacherSignUpForm` in another `<form>` tag. You can then handle the data separately in your view.

In this case, you will have to use a custom `View` instead of `CreateView` because `CreateView` typically only allows for one `form_class`.

You can do something like

```
class TeacherSignupView(View):
    def get_context_data(self):
        return {'user_form': self.user_form_class, 'teacher_form': self.teacher_form_class}

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, 'form.html', self.get_context_data())

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user_data = {
           'some-user-field': request.POST.get('some-user-field')
        }
        teacher_data = {
           'some-teacher-field': request.POST.get('some-teacher-field')
        }

        # Handle each set of form data individually
        user_form = self.user_form_class(user_data)

        # Check valid
        if user_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()
            # If user form is valid and user data is saved, then proceed with teacher data
            teacher_data["user"] = user  # add the user relation here
            teacher_form = self.teacher_form_class(teacher_data)
            if teacher_form.is_valid():
                teacher_form.save()

        return render_to_response('index.html', self.get_context_data())
```

Comment: In your template you need to change `form` to `teacher_form`. For example if you had `{{ form.as_p }}` then you'd change it to `{{ teacher_form.as_p }}`

Answer (score 0):

> But I want that a student or a teacher won't be able to create account, unless all fields are filled in.

They're starting to sound like separate models.

If they share some commonality, or you want to use them in the same place sometimes, I would recommend looking into [django-polymorphic](https://github.com/django-polymorphic/django-polymorphic).  It sounds scary, but it's just a way to have an inheritance tree for models, and use the parent class when you can, as if it was a normal model on its own.  It has fantastic admin and form integration, and feels like part of django itself.

In your instance, you'll be able to have your models defined as such:

```
class BaseUser(PolymorphicModel):
    photo = models.FileField(...)
    phone = models.CharField(...)
    ...


class Student(BaseUser):
    student_ID = models.CharField(...)
    ...

class Teacher(BaseUser):
    academic_title = models.CharField(...)
    website = models.URLField(...)
    bio = models.TextField(...)
    ...
```

And the database, along with polymorphic and your bog-standard `ModelForm`s, will ensure completeness for you.

Comment: This is some advanced stuff.. This is my first time when Im working with forms, I need some proper guidence. Docs are bad for me, I learn by example. But I can't find an example of what I need..

Comment: That's fair enough; polymorphic is something you should reach for once you're comfortable, but it is absolutely the right fit for your problem.  Keep it in your back pocket, and come back here when you feel like you're ready.